# trigger compliance scan in Azure policies from CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I used the 'Start-AzPolicyComplianceScan' from the PowerShell to trigger a compliance scan for the policies assigned.
what is the equivalent command to trigger a compliance scan on the policies from the Azure CLI tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the equivalent command to trigger a compliance scan on the policies from the Azure CLI tool?

You can use the below Azure CLI cmdlet to trigger a compliance scan on the policies at the **current subscription scope**.

`az policy state trigger-scan`

Or use the below cmdlet to trigger a policy compliance evaluation for your  **resource group**:

`az policy state trigger-scan -g "myRg"`